# Javascript function to change button color (found off of SO) won't work (Update)

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried applying the techniques I found from using other topics posted on this exact issue (reason I believe they won't work is described above my last bit of code in this post), for some reason mine just isn't working. Here is my entire code, it *should run. I just need the button color to match the color of the randomly assigned gender.
Sidenote: for some reason this code is not working in the snippet runner, but it is working in Sublime)

```js
var images = document.getElementById("images");
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttons');
var input = document.getElementById('namer');
var name;
var oz = Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 2 + 1)) + 2;


input.onkeypress = function submitbabyName(event) {
  //event.keycode 13 is the "enter" key
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert(input.value);
    name = input.value;
    alert(name);
    //this removes the input box after hitting "enter
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
    //this takes you to the next page after hitting "enter"
    advanceTo(scenario.two);
  }
};


var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("This", name);
};

var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
};

var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<a href='#'class='button' onClick=" + buttonList[i][1] + ">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</a>";
  }
};

var advanceTo = function(s) {
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};

//gender assignment randomized between 1 and 2
var usergender = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
if (usergender != 1) {
  gender = "boy";
  //document.getElementsByClassName("game-buttons")[0].style.background = "#89CFF0";
} else {
  gender = "girl";
  //document.getElementsByClassName("game-buttons")[0].style.background = "#f4c2c2";
}

scenario = {}
var scenario = {
  start: {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg",
    text: "Hey thanks for clicking on this and trying to help lol. I just need the button color to reflect the given gender which is auto assigned randomly on refresh atm for simplicities sake. Right now, gender is: \n" + gender + ". Try to get button color to be blue for boys, pink for girls.",
  },

  two: {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/9p8m7v1u7/6899639786_d517c4cce3_z.jpg",
    text: "Hopefully these buttons work now ://.",
    buttons: [
      ["YAY ITS BLUE OR PINK.", "advanceTo(scenario.thankyou)"],
      ["F*** ITS NOT", "advanceTo(scenario.damnit)"]
    ]

  },
  //------------------------------------------------
  thankyou: {
    image: "https://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "WOOOOOOOO.",
    buttons: [
      ["GOD BLESS IF I KNEW HOW TO MAKE CONFETTI RN YOU'D BE SEEING IT"]
    ]
  },
  damnit: {
    image: "https://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "PLS TRY AGAIN",
    buttons: [
      ["CAN DO", "advanceTo(scenario.two)"],
      ["no thanks"]
    ]
  },

};

advanceTo(scenario.start)
```

```css
<style type="text/css">body {
  background-color: #e1c8ea;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* centers content in screen*/
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%
  /*margin is super necessary to make bg color show up for some reason */
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

#images {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/*this is that box thing that you type your name into*/

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.game-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Changes width of all buttons. ?F**** up lettering though */
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* what kind of hover cursor you want */
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: black;
  /* color of text */
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #d1eac8;
}

.button:hover {
  /* color of background while mouse is over it */
  background: #bcd2b4;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

</style>
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="images">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="text"></div>
    <input id="namer" onkeypress="nocluewhatthisdoeslol()" placeholder='Name yoself here'>
    <div id="buttons" class="game-buttons">
    </div>
  </div>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: You need to assign to the style after you recreate all the buttons in `changeButtons`

Comment: Um can you change the part with the f word?

Comment: There is now **a lot** of code here. Is all that really necessary to illustrate the problem? Note *minimal* in [mcve]. By reducing the code to just enough to reproduce the error, you may find the issue yourself. If not, you will make it much easier for us to help you as we don't have to wade through irrelevant code.

Comment: On a side note, the code is not running as you have no buttons defined in the first step of the scenario. Therefore `buttonList` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by id

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);?
```

Try also

```
document.querySelectorAll("mybutton").forEach((element) => element.style.background = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the selectors using `querySelectorAll()`, then pass the **nodeList** into a function. The function contains a **for** loop to iterate over the **nodeList** or an ***HTML Collection*** then runs a function to change the values on the call of your **eventListener**.

I added a function that will run a loop that runs on both nodelists (***querySelectorAll***) and html collections (***getElementsByClassName***) also a conditional that checks if a single element or multiple elements are being passed.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons')
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons')
// change the parameter in the call of the function changeButtonColor to a single element or HTML COllection or NodeList
const eventChange = (e) => {
  e.target.style.background = 'blue'
  e.target.style.color = 'white'
}

const changeButtonColor = (el) => {
  // multiple nodes (nodeList) or elements HTML Collection
  if (el instanceof NodeList || el instanceof HTMLCollection) {
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].addEventListener('click', eventChange)
    }
    // single element  
  } else {
    el.addEventListener('click', eventChange)
  }
}

// NodeList querySelectorAll multiple or single
changeButtonColor(buttons) // or buttons[0] will also work

// or HTML Collection getElementsByClassName multi or single
// changeButtonColor(btns) or btns[0] will also work
```

```css
.buttons {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Changes width of all buttons. ?Fucks up lettering though */
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: black;
  /* color of text */
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
<button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
<button class="buttons">Button 3</button>
<button class="buttons">Button 4</button>
<button class="buttons">Button 5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice, don't manipulate the style directly, add , remove or update classes as requirements.

Here I simply add the a class for gender to the `body` then create  style rule for the first `a` tag in the `#buttons` container. I could just have easily add the gender css class to any element. Note that in your first step there is no buttons in the DOM so you can't add to the buttons them self at this stage.

```js
var images = document.getElementById("images");
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttons');
var input = document.getElementById('namer');
var name;
var oz = Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 2 + 1)) + 2;


input.onkeypress = function submitbabyName(event) {
  //event.keycode 13 is the "enter" key
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    //alert(input.value);
    name = input.value;
    //alert(name);
    //this removes the input box after hitting "enter
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
    //this takes you to the next page after hitting "enter"
    
    //This looks like as good a place as any to set the class for gender on the body
    console.log(gender);
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add(gender);
    
    advanceTo(scenario.two);
  }
};


var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("This", name);
};

var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
};

var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  //Check buttonList is something
  if (buttonList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
      buttonBox.innerHTML += "<a href='#'class='button' onClick=" + buttonList[i][1] + ">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</a>";
    }
  }
};

var advanceTo = function(s) {
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};

//gender assignment randomized between 1 and 2
var usergender = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
if (usergender != 1) {
  gender = "boy";
} else {
  gender = "girl";
}

scenario = {}
var scenario = {
  start: {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg",
    text: "Hey thanks for clicking on this and trying to help lol. I just need the button color to reflect the given gender which is auto assigned randomly on refresh atm for simplicities sake. Right now, gender is: \n" + gender + ". Try to get button color to be blue for boys, pink for girls.",
  },

  two: {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/9p8m7v1u7/6899639786_d517c4cce3_z.jpg",
    text: "Hopefully these buttons work now ://.",
    buttons: [
      ["YAY ITS BLUE OR PINK.", "advanceTo(scenario.thankyou)"],
      ["F*** ITS NOT", "advanceTo(scenario.damnit)"]
    ]

  },
  //------------------------------------------------
  thankyou: {
    image: "https://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "WOOOOOOOO.",
    buttons: [
      ["GOD BLESS IF I KNEW HOW TO MAKE CONFETTI RN YOU'D BE SEEING IT"]
    ]
  },
  damnit: {
    image: "https://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "PLS TRY AGAIN",
    buttons: [
      ["CAN DO", "advanceTo(scenario.two)"],
      ["no thanks"]
    ]
  },

};

advanceTo(scenario.start)
```

```css
<style type="text/css">body {
  background-color: #e1c8ea;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* centers content in screen*/
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.boy #buttons>a:first-of-type {
  background-color: #89CFF0;
}

.girl #buttons>a:first-of-type {
  background-color: #f4c2c2;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%
  /*margin is super necessary to make bg color show up for some reason */
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

#images {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/*this is that box thing that you type your name into*/

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.game-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Changes width of all buttons. ?F**** up lettering though */
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* what kind of hover cursor you want */
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: black;
  /* color of text */
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #d1eac8;
}

.button:hover {
  /* color of background while mouse is over it */
  background: #bcd2b4;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

</style>
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <input id="namer" onkeypress="nocluewhatthisdoeslol()" placeholder='Name yoself here'>
  <div id="buttons" class="game-buttons">
  </div>
</div>
```